# Ceph Rados GW Proxy

Tags: ceph

I've been given an access key to a Ceph cluster that runs radoswgw to provide S3. The key allows bucket creation, object reading etc. I don't admin the Ceph or radosgw.

I have a group of users that want to use the Ceph object store, but need data isolation. I can't really distribute the master access key to them.

Is there a system/proxy I can put in front of this Ceph/radosgw that can use this master key to provision/read/write to the Ceph cluster backend, whilst issuing and managing access keys to users on the front end?